# Why am I seeing binding errors related to AreRowDetailsFrozen and HeadersVisibility for Datagrids in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
>   AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid', AncestorLevel='1''.
>   BindingExpression:Path=AreRowDetailsFrozen; DataItem=null; target
>   element is 'DataGridDetailsPresenter' (Name=''); target property is
>   'SelectiveScrollingOrientation' (type 'SelectiveScrollingOrientation')
>   System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
>   AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid', AncestorLevel='1''.
>   BindingExpression:Path=HeadersVisibility; DataItem=null; target
>   element is 'DataGridRowHeader' (Name=''); target property is
>   'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')

These errors appear in the immediate window in WPF. Why does this happen, and how can I stop it?

Comment: I had the same problem and figured out, that it was because of my clumsy way to asynchronous loading datagrid data :(  Specifically it was some kind of busy indicator with action parameter and so on...  When I removed that piece of functionality, the problem was solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150811234933/http://wpf.codeplex.com/discussions/47047) has details of workarounds for this issue. This one worked for me:

Add the following code to global styles:

```
<Style.Triggers>
     <Trigger Property="HeadersVisibility" Value="Column">         
          <Setter Property="RowHeaderWidth" Value="0" />
     </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: The link to the post has changed. Today (2018) it points to a list of discussions. You can still find the discussion by its title: "Bug with DataGrid.HeadersVisibility?"

Answer (score 1):

Was having the same issue. I made a barebones WPF 4.7 app and in my case the SizeToContent attribute was causing it.

I had a StatusBar with its DataContext set to RelativeSource AncestorType=Window and a DataGrid was a sibling to it both within a DockPanel. The root Window had its SizeToContent set to Width.

When items were added to the DataGrid the binding errors you describe appeared. Without SizeToContent they don't. Using ElementName=rootWindow in the StatusBar instead of the Ancestor shenanigans also fixed it.